# Copy bundle resources

Tags: objective-c, bundle, resourcebundle

I'm programming on objective-c. I've removed all files from MyTarget -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle resources. How can I return it because my project doesn't work?

Comment: use version control system and rollback to working commit. :) or manually select your resources in project navigator tab (left side), then open file inspector in Utilities (right side) and check target membership.

Comment: +1 for using the file inspector - made it much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them again. If your project structure is good then you should have them in the Resources folder. If not, it's a great time to fix your project structure, but unfortunately you will have to add every single resource file manually.

Also, as SDK is shipped with git nowadays, it's good to use it and commit your changes. If you used git, reverting this would be as easy as reverting the project file to the previous version.

Comment: See Evgen's comment above. If you select items in the project navigator on the left - you can select a whole lot at once - then view the Target Membership in the Utilities file inspector tab on the right, you can add or remove them all at once.